# Salesforce Integration User Best Practice

Tags: api, web-services, integration

**Question-**
Is having a dedicated user per integration a personal choice or it is a good practice?

**Background**
We have about 5 different Integrations with Salesforce. Each integration serves different purpose and needs. e.g. one is a bidirectional sync, other is a 1 directional sync from external system to SF, yet another is a 1 directional sync from SF to external system.

Currently we have a dedicated Integration User for each Integration.
The reason as I understand is that, each integration user has different permissions, and also for whatever reason if we have problems with one user account, we do not want all the integrations to be affected. Having a dedicated user per integration also would allow us to better debug and mitigate issues.

Can someone suggest ideas as to how to decide - if it is better to create a new integration user or use the same user for more than one integrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the strongest arguments to reuse the same user for multiple integrations are:

- User licenses are expensive and some organizations don't have many unused licenses.
- It is easier to maintain a single user with a single profile.

However, I prefer having separate users per integration for some of the same reasons you already mentioned:

- Security: each integration user has access only to what it needs and nothing else.
- Ability to better isolate and debug issues that arise.

Personally, I like the approach of having a stripped-down integration Profile assigned to all my integration users and assigning permissions via Permission Sets; it makes thing easier to manage.

Comment: Thank you Arepa for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: I would say that, unless you fall in the first bucket (few licenses available), it is definitely a better practice to have isolation of concerns. Imagine a hacker gets access to the credentials for one of your integrations; if you only have one user, now they have access to a lot more data than if you had separate users.

Comment: Thanks Arepa for giving me pointers to ponder upon.

Comment: Great question! I would like to see what others respond.